# Type-error in shared variable in theano

Tags: typeerror, theano

I get TypeError: an integer is required on line 5:

```
rng1=np.random.RandomState(1234)
dtensor = T.TensorType(dtype=theano.config.floatX,broadcastable=  (False,)*5)
V=dtensor('V')
b_shp=(W.shape[0],)
b=theano.shared(np.asarray(rng1.uniform(low=-5,high=5,size=b_shp),dtype=V.dtype),name='b',borrow=True)
```

However if i change b_shape to b_shp=(2,0), it gives no error.

Comment: What is `W`? Is it symbolic or concrete?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `W` is a symbolic tensor (e.g. a shared variable). For example,

```
import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

rng1 = np.random.RandomState(1234)
dtensor = T.TensorType(dtype=theano.config.floatX, broadcastable=(False,) * 5)
V = dtensor('V')
W = theano.shared(np.asarray(rng1.uniform(low=-5, high=5, size=(2, 3)), dtype=V.dtype), name='W', borrow=True)
b_shp = (W.shape[0],)
b = theano.shared(np.asarray(rng1.uniform(low=-5, high=5, size=b_shp), dtype=V.dtype), name='b', borrow=True)
```

If this assumption is correct, the error `TypeError: an integer is required` occurs because `W.shape[0]` is a symbolic expression but numpy needs a concrete integer. You could probably change it to `W.get_value().shape[0]` to solve the problem though this is messy and a cleaner solution would depend on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to use it with conv3D by adding the following lines of code:                        d=theano.shared(np.asarray([2,2,2],dtype=V.dtype))
    conv_temp=T.nnet.conv3D(V,W,b,d) f=theano.function([V],conv_temp)

Comment: In this example `W` is a [`SharedVariable`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/examples.html#using-shared-variables) so `get_value` should be available.